# Get hostname in xmonad/xmobar config file

Tags: haskell, xmonad

My dotfiles are 99% similar between computers but there are minor tweaks that I keep
for various minor settings. 
My plan was to discriminate using an if statement based on hostname. 
something that would look as follows in a shell config like bashrc or zshrc

```
if [ $(hostname) == 'host1' ]; then
# things to do differently on host1.
elif [ $(hostname) == 'host2' ]; then
# things to do differently on host2.
fi
```

I suspect that xmobar is simply a config file that is parsed with no real haskell in it.
Any thoughts on how to get something similar to what I have with a shell in xmobar?

Mainly I am wanting to modify the widths and network interfaces in xmobar something like

```
Config {
if hostname == "host1" 
then
    font = "xft:Fixed-9",
    position = Static { xpos = 0, ypos = 0, width = 1280, height = 16 },
else if hostname == "host2"
then
    font = "xft:Fixed-12",
    position = Static { xpos = 1920, ypos = 0, width = 1800, height = 16 },
lowerOnStart = True,
commands = [
    -- if here as well to switch between eth0 and wls3 
    Run Network "wls3" ["-t","Net: <rx>, <tx>","-H","200","-L","10","-h","#cc9393","-l","#709080","-n","#705050"] 10,
    Run Date "%a %b %_d %l:%M" "date" 10,
    Run Battery ["-t", "Bat: <left>%","-L","10","-H","11","-l","#CC9393","-h","#709080"] 10,
    Run StdinReader
],
sepChar = "%",
alignSep = "}{",
template = "%StdinReader% }{ %multicpu% | %memory% | %Vol% | %wls3% | %battery% |   <fc=#709080>%date%</fc>"

}
```

I realize my syntax is wishful and likely wrong, I love xmonad but have not learned haskell syntax yet.

Comment: the config file of xmonad is just a piece of Haskell code, so you can get the hostname by `getEnv "HOST"` or `getHostName` in `Network` package. However I don't think this is the answer you want, so could you explain what you actually want to accomplish in xmonad's config file?

Comment: I just updated with a snippet from my xmobar.hs file. I suppose the ".hs" ending should have tipped me off to it being code and not simply config but haskell syntax is very foreign to me.

Comment: @bertabus I'm not sure about the recent versions of `xmobar`, but the older versions generally parsed `.xmobarrc` file. Because of that you couldn't enter comments in that file. If that is the case still now, I don't think so you can use the `if else` expression in that file. I would be happy if this is not the case in the recent versions, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `xmonad.hs` is a haskell file, you can use the package [hostname](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hostname), to find it's name:

In ghci:

```
λ> import Network.HostName
λ> getHostName
Loading package hostname-1.0 ... linking ... done.
"hostname1"
```

It seems you want to have different `xmobar` settings for your host. One way to achieve that would be to write a function that will create a new `.xmobarrc` file for your given host. It's type definition will look something like this:

```
createXmobarrc :: String -> IO ()
createXmobarrc hostname = undefined -- Write your logic
```

You can then call this method in the appropriate place in your `xmonad.hs` file using the following pattern:

```
main = do
 hostname <- getHostName
 createXmobarrc hostname -- produce appropriate .xmobarrc file for a given host
 -- other xmonad stuff follows here
```